# Singularity of Riemann-Liouville Fractional Derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives, fractional-calculus

I have recently started studying fractional order calculus and it seems that the definition of the fractional order differentiation, in the Riemann-Liouville (RL) sense, has singularities. To explain my point, let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $f(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. We have
\begin{align}
D^{\alpha} f(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^t f(\tau)(t-\tau)^{-\alpha}\ d\tau.
\end{align}
Performing integration by parts and carrying out the differentiation, we further have
\begin{align}
D^{\alpha} f(t) = \frac{f(0)t^{-\alpha}}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}+\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\int_{0}^t \dot{f}(\tau)(t-\tau)^{-\alpha}\ d\tau.
\end{align}
The term $t^{-\alpha}$ brings about a singularity at $t=0$. So, can we say that (i) for a differentiable function the RL derivative of order $\alpha\in (0,1)$ is singular at $t=0$ unless $f(0) = 0$; (ii) if $f(0) = 0$, then the RL derivative corresponds to that of the Caputo?

Comment: I believe the power on the $(t-\tau)^{-\alpha}$ should change and there should be another coefficient?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, I've followed the definition of RL derivative, $D^{\alpha} = (d/dt)D^{-(1-\alpha)}$. First, integration by parts and then, differentiation by Leibniz rule. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Never mind, mistake on my end. I think this should be fine then.